# Count commas in line of text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text file and I'm trying to count the number of commas in the first line of the file using excel VB and then do an action if there are 3 - but something is wrong. When I use the replace method (commented out in this example below) the macro fails, and when I use the Split method it ALWAYS does the action, no matter what value I add in place of 3.

```
   'Load txt file into array
    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    dataArray = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbLf)
    Close #1

    'Test first line if it has three commas
    If Len(dataArray(0).value) - Len(Replace(dataArray(0).value, ",", "")) = 3 Then
    'If dataArray(0).Split(",").Length = 3 Then

   'Add comma to start of strings
        For i = LBound(dataArray) To UBound(dataArray)

            dataArray(i) = "," & dataArray(i)
        Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.value` appears to be the problem. VBA doesn't have properties the same way .NET does.

Replace your uncommented out IF statement with this:

```
If Len(dataArray(0)) - Len(Replace(dataArray(0), ",", "")) = 3 Then
```

Comment: Thanks - I did also try it without the .Values and it didn't work - then I finally realised that I had a sub named "Replace" in one of my modules - not sure how but this clearly messed things up - when I renamed that everything worked fine.